# How to programmatically trigger doubletap event in ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, dom-events

How can I do it? I already looked into ionic forum, google results, and didn't find anything useful. Also, I already tried triggering `dblclick`, `dbltap`, `doubletap`, `doubleClick`, and even multiple `tap` and `click` events, but nothing seems to work.

I know some events that I used don't even exist, I was just trying to see if ionic would recognize them somehow. Also, I tried the click events because the app runs just fine in the browser, so I thought it could work in the specs as well.

If it helps, I need this to unit test my feature. I have an `ion-list`, and when an user double taps an `ion-item`, it marks the item as checked. My markup currently look like this:

```
<ion-item on-double-tap="ctrl.toggleProductConfirmation(product)" ...
```

And my spec, like this:

```
describe('when checking an item', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.element.find('ion-item').eq(0).trigger('doubletap');
  });

** specs here **
```

One last detail: I use phantom JS to run my specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the same question in the ionic forum, and, fortunately, someone was able to help me.

In ionic, apparently you can always use `ionic.trigger` to trigger any event you want, and this includes `doubletap` (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.EventController/#trigger).

The docs are a little confusing, so I'll post my code here to help someone with the same problem:

```
ionic.trigger('doubletap', { target: this.element.find('ion-item').get(0) });
```

Because I'm using jquery in my specs, I had to use `get(0)` to retrieve the DOM element itself, as passing the jQuery object directly didn't work for me.

Link to my thread in ionic forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-programmatically-trigger-doubletap-event/41264

Comment: For me at least, is not working. Could you give some context for the code? It's a controller?

Comment: After trying your way and failing using `this.element.find('ion-item').get(0)`.
I tried with this `$('#some-item').get(0)` and worked.
I'm just sharing this for someone that can have a problem like mine, or if you want to update it. Nevertheless, you answer helped me. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, `this.element` was an jquery element which I got the same way you did. Glad I could help!

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but you should edit your answer to make that obvious. It will make easier to understand you contribution. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possible in ionic because Ionic removes the default 300ms delay to give the application more native feel. [Ref](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/)

You can try firing the events in the element with the delay disabled as follows

```
<div data-tap-disabled="true">
    <div id="google-map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But, assuming we disable the tap, will the doubletap work on the device?

Comment: the double tap will be disabled only for the element you specify